# C++11: Compatiability with pthreads, static class function, and -pg flag

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I stumbled into a weird bug involving C++11, pthreads, and the -pg flag.  It seems that my threads are getting stuck on a C++ library routine line mcount.c file when it invokes a static function in any of my classes.

```
Sleeping
Awakened
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7bc6148 in pthread_join (threadid=140737333020416, thread_return=0x7fffffffe4f8)
    at pthread_join.c:89
89  pthread_join.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  17   Thread 0x7fffef3cd700 (LWP 6152) "test.o" __mcount_internal (frompc=4198422, selfpc=4206354)
    at mcount.c:72
  16   Thread 0x7fffefbce700 (LWP 6151) "test.o" __mcount_internal (frompc=4211225, selfpc=4212043)
    at mcount.c:72
  15   Thread 0x7ffff03cf700 (LWP 6150) "test.o" __mcount_internal (frompc=4211225, selfpc=4212043)
    at mcount.c:72
 ......
    at mcount.c:72
  3    Thread 0x7ffff63db700 (LWP 6138) "test.o" __mcount_internal (frompc=4206451, selfpc=4211201)
    at mcount.c:72
  2    Thread 0x7ffff6bdc700 (LWP 6136) "test.o" __mcount_internal (frompc=4206732, selfpc=4211201)
    at mcount.c:72
* 1    Thread 0x7ffff7fd6740 (LWP 6135) "test.o" 0x00007ffff7bc6148 in pthread_join (
    threadid=140737333020416, thread_return=0x7fffffffe4f8) at pthread_join.c:89
(gdb) thread 17
[Switching to thread 17 (Thread 0x7fffef3cd700 (LWP 6152))]
#0  __mcount_internal (frompc=4198422, selfpc=4206354) at mcount.c:72
72  mcount.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __mcount_internal (frompc=4198422, selfpc=4206354) at mcount.c:72
#1  0x00007ffff71d0b94 in mcount () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/_mcount.S:48
#2  0x00007ffff7ff7030 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000000001a in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000008800191 in ?? ()
#5  0x000000000000001a in ?? ()
#6  0x00007ffff7ff7030 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000005 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000040 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000402f12 in Helper::remove (vec=0x8800191, pos=0, p=0x5) at Helpers.hpp:100
```

The threads *should* all exit after main thread prints "Awakened" but they dont, and when I interrupt the program, they are all in the mcount.c file.  Which seems be called in between my call to Helper::remove and the initialization of the function variables in the Helper::Remove.

Indicated by

```
#9  0x0000000000402f12 in Helper::remove (vec=0x8800191, pos=0, p=0x5) at Helpers.hpp:100
```

which should hold the values (vec=0x7ffff7ff7030, pos=26, p=0x8800191), the last variable makes me wonder if I am some how overwriting the stack. (these values were retrieved from stack frame #10).

Line 100 in Helpers.hpp is simply the function declaration:

```
  static bool remove(WFVector *vec, int pos, void *p){
```

Can anyone explain why the inclusion of the -pg flag causes threads to get stuck in the static function?

Code compiled with: `g++-4.7 -DDEBUG=1 -g -pg -std=c++0x  -mcx16  -m64   tester.cpp -o test.o -I /usr/include/boost  -lpthread`
and testing with `GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04`

Answer (score 1):

gprof is known to not support multi-threaded applications. See if [this workaround](http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html) solves the problem. Most people simply use another profiling tool anyways.

I personally prefer [Linux's built-in perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). Searching for "gprof threads" will give plenty of results from SO, with various suggestions for profiling tools.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the -pg flag fixes the error. It took me a *long* time to figure it out and it was only dumb luck that I figured it out.  So I am posting this bug in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Comment: A bug in what? gcc, gdb, Ubuntu?